# ag-grid in angular scroll bar is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I gave 1000 of rows and 50 columns. Here everything is working fine.

> but it vartical scroll is not rolling, horizontal scroll is not
> showing

**How to fix is ?**

**HTML**

```html
<ag-grid-angular 
    #agGrid 
    style="width: 100%; height: 550px;" 
    id="myGrid" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
    [enableSorting]="true" 
    [multiSortKey]="multiSortKey" 
    [animateRows]="true"
    [paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize" 
    [pagination]="true" [enableRangeSelection]="true" 
    [enableFilter]="true"
    [floatingFilter]="true" 
    [getRowHeight]="getRowHeight" 
    [suppressPaginationPanel]="true"
    [suppressScrollOnNewData]="true" 
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" 
  >
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

**Screen**

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce this in plunker?

Comment: hey, can you provide me the solution to avoid that problem?

Answer (score 2):

same problem here; it started happening with the upgrade from v19 to v20 of the ag-angular-grid;  issue is being tracked (https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2962)

Answer (score 1):

Remove 
`[suppressScrollOnNewData]="true"`
from ag-grid selector

Comment: can you create a plunkr

Answer (score 1):

import ag-grid-community css files instead of ag-grid

```
 @import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
 @import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css';
```